# Doubt in proof of integrating by part

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

In the proof of integration by parts given in the photo below I see f(X)•g(x) get differntiated and I see the dx below them move to the RHS, so I left hand side we should have d(f(X)•g(X)) right? I am not able to understand how did dx come in the LHS[image]

Comment: Yes but I didn't understand how did LHS get dx multiplied with it

Comment: Ahh, now I got what you're asking. Sorry!

Comment: Note that integration by parts is just the product rule in reverse. By the product rule, $(fg)' = f'g + f g'$. Now integrate both sides from $a$ to $b$ to obtain $\int_a^b (fg)' \, dx = \int_a^b f' g \, dx + \int_a^b f' g \, dx$. Finally notice that the left hand side is equal to $fg \rvert_a^b$.

Comment: @littleO - I wish you had written $(fg) \rvert_a^b$

Comment: @stevengregory True, that would've been a little more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof keeps repeating the same typo. When they write $\int fgdx$, it should be $fg$. Or if we work with definite integrals, $\int_a^b(fg^\prime+gf^\prime)dx=[fg]_a^b=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)$. However, the later special case $g=\int vdx$ has been handled correctly.